# Definition of elongation in SHM?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

If we have a weight oscillating in a vertical spring, is the elongation defined as a **position** (a coordinate $\vec{r}$) or as the **distance** (i.e $|\vec{r}-\vec{r_0}|$) between the position and the equilibrium? Or is the elongation just the length of the loaded spring measured from the length of the unloaded spring taken as zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally defined as the latter. Of course you can just set $\vec{r_0}=0 $ and then your elongation just equals your usual coordinate $ \vec{r}$.